# Stripes: LocalizableError can't find resources

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jar, stripes

My project is in **Java EE**. I got two modules **war** and **ejb**. When I remove stripes jar from libraries of **ejb** module and include it to war module Localizable error works fine.

But when I did that war module cant connect to **ejb** session bean(I'm using stripes-injection-enricher).

Project sees the `StripesResources.properties` file because I can get string like that in **jsp** file:

```
 <fmt:message key="layout.otherLanguage"/>
```

in resources I got:

```
layout.otherLanguage=French
```

it works. But `LocalizableError` or `SimpleError` not working in **actionbean** file:

```
errors.add("username",
                new LocalizableError("primaryEmailNotFound"));
```

In resources file:

```
project.action.LoginActionBean.primaryEmailNotFound=wrong login
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved when I delete stripes.jar from ejb module and deploy .war file instead of .ear file.